# Connect an Heroku app to a Ionos domain Name

Tags: heroku, ionos

I have developed an app and make it available via Heroku. Now I would like to add a custom domain name via Ionos however I don't know how to configure it. When using EC2 instances I would configure an static ip address but for Heroku, I don't know what to do. I have checked other post about this but none a precise or recent about what to do.
Thanks for you attention and have a Great day.

Answer (score 2):

Had the exact same issue and here's how I made it work (just specifying I'm not an expert, so take this answer with a grain of salt):

First you'd have to go to Heroku in your app setting and then add the domain name you bought. It's important that you write the host when adding it, like put either `www.` or `*.` at the beginning of the domain. It will give you back a DNS target which you will then need to use on Ionos.

Secondly, you'd have to bind this DNS target on Ionos using a CNAME. Just go to your domains, click the one in your list, then open `DNS` and click `Add a record`. Choose CNAME and then put `www` as provider and past the DNS target you copied in `target` field. Finally, confirm the changes

Wait a few seconds/minutes, navigate to `www.yourdomain.whatever` and tada!

About static IP address, Heroku made some docs, and that won't work, you'd have to use dynamic ones. So in a nutshell, use CNAMEs instead of A records

[Here are some docs if you want to dig more into this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain)

Comment: That's exactly how it works! Thanks for the description!